# How to add information from called method to Visual Studio Test output console in TFS 2018 R3

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tfs, msbuild

I try to add additional information to the output console or log file in TFS2018 from a called method, because of broken unit test only on the build server and too less information about exception.
Let's say we have a method (in this example properties):

```
public GsModule GdiModule
{
  get
  {
    if (_gdiModule == null)
    {
      string directory = (new FileInfo(typeof(GsModule).Assembly.Location)).DirectoryName;
      string path = Path.Combine(directory, "WinGDI.txv");

      _gdiModule = (GsModule) SystemObjects.DynamicLinker.LoadModule(path, false, true);
    }

    return _gdiModule;
  }
}
```

I would like to get information about the path and directory from this method in output in Visual Studio Test Task in Team Foundation Server 2018.

I tried with:

```
 Trace.WriteLine($"GDI directory: {directory}"));
```

and NUinit.Framework

```
TestContext.WriteLine($"GDI directory: {directory}"));
```

but without success.

*PS: The build is configurated to x64 | Release and `<DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>`*

Do you have any idea how can I get this kind of information?

Comment: What task are you using in TFS 2018 . VSbuild task or Vstest task? Do you need to add parameters to the task or add parameters to the project for output?

Comment: Thank you Jeff,
 
I'm using Visual Studio Build -> Visual Studio Test Platform Installer -> and after Visual Studio Test. 
I wanted to throw the value of few parameters to the output console or log file.
I found the better way to debug unit tests on the build server https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/SSH_Remote_Debugging.html